# Problem with QMap return as reference?

Tags: c++, qt, reference, qmap

Greetings all,

I have a code snippet as follows :

```
class AppCtx {

private:
 QMap<QString,IRzPlugin*> pluginsMap;

public :
 void addPlugin(IRzPlugin *plugin)
 {
   pluginsMap.insert(plugin->getPluginUID(),plugin);
 }

 QMap<QString,IRzPlugin*> & getPlugins()
 {
  return pluginsMap;
 }
}
```

In my client code I access the QMap as follows.But the application breaks
where it access the 'plugins.size()'

```
class MainWindow
.
.

{
 void registerPlugins(AppCtx *appctx)
 {
   QMap<QString,IRzPlugin*> plugins=appctx->getPlugins();

   qDebug("Num of plugins %d",plugins.size()); //Breaks here

   QList<IRzPlugin*> listPlugins=plugins.values();

   for(int i=0;i<listPlugins.size();i++)
   {

   }
 }
```

Debug info is given below :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fff057a16f0 (LWP 9069)]
0x0000000000406ba1 in QMap<QString, IRzPlugin*>::size (this=0x405c2b)
    at /opt/qtsdk-2010.02/qt/include/QtCore/qmap.h:178
178     inline int size() const { return d->size; }
(gdb) back
#0  0x0000000000406ba1 in QMap<QString, IRzPlugin*>::size (this=0x405c2b)
    at /opt/qtsdk-2010.02/qt/include/QtCore/qmap.h:178
#1  0x0000000000406736 in MainWindow::registerPlugins (this=0x7fff0d7c98f0)
    at /work/svn-checkout/osaka3d/osaka3d/tags/iter07/prototype/osaka3d/rinzo/ui/mainwindow.cpp:23


}
```

any tips?

Thanks in advance,
umanga

Comment: If you're not planning on changing the map it's also not necessary to return a reference to the map because Qt uses copy on write mechanism for most objects. This means the data is not duplicated if a construct a copy of the QMap until you actually change something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice you are copying the QMap with

```
QMap<QString,IRzPlugin*> plugins=appctx->getPlugins();
```

I assume you want to take a reference to it i.e.

```
QMap<QString,IRzPlugin*>& plugins=appctx->getPlugins();
```

If you only need a reference-to-const then the [docs](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qmap.html#QMap-2) say that it is implicitly shared so it's not such a big deal.

If this helps your problem then it must be something to do with copying the `QMap`.

**Edit**

Since this didn't help your problem I think you need to check the pointer `appctx` that gets passed into `registerPlugins` and check if it points to a valid object.

Comment: thanks for the answer,I use your method and changed 'pluginsMap' into a pointer (*pluginsMap) .But still same issue.

Comment: @umanga: In that case you should look at the pointer `appctx` that's passed in to `registerPlugins` and check whether that is pointing to a valid object. It might be uninitialised, pointing to deleted memory, or corrupted in some other fashion.

Comment: thanks Troubadour for the tip. that was the issue, it was uninitialized !